# How to properly tag a list of documenta by Gensim TaggedDocument()

Tags: nlp, gensim, doc2vec

I would like to tag a list of documents by `Gensim TaggedDocument()`, and then pass these documents as in input of `Doc2Vec()`.

I have read the documentation about `TaggedDocument` [here](https://radimrehurek.com/gensim/models/doc2vec.html#gensim.models.doc2vec.TaggedDocument), but I don' t have understood what exactly are the parameters `words` and `tags`.

I have tried:

```
texts = [[word for word in document.lower().split()]
          for document in X.values]

texts = [[token for token in text]
          for text in texts]

model = gensim.models.Doc2Vec(texts, vector_size=200)
model.train(texts, total_examples=len(texts), epochs=10)
```

But I get the error `'list' object has no attribute 'words'`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`Doc2Vec` expects an iterable collection of texts that are each (shaped like) the example `TaggedDocument` class, with both `words` and `tags` properties.

The `words` can be your tokenized text (as a list), but the `tags` should be a list of document-tags that should be receive learned vectors via the `Doc2Vec` algorithm. Most often, these are unique IDs, one per document. (You can just use plain int indexes, if that works as a way to refer to your documents elsewhere, or string IDs.) Note that `tags` must be a list-of-tags, even if you're only providing one per document.

You are simply providing a list of lists-of-words, thus generating the error.

Try instead just the single line to initialize `texts`:

```
texts = [TaggedDocument(
             words=[word for word in document.lower().split()],
             tags=[i]
         ) for i, document in enumerate(X.values)]
```

Also, you don't need to call `train()` if you've supplied `texts` when the `Doc2Vec` was created. (By supplying the corpus at initialization, `Doc2Vec` will automatically do both an initial vocabulary-discovery scan and then your specified number of training passes.)

You should look at working examples for inspiration, such as the `doc2vec-lee.ipynb` runnable Jupyter notebook that's included with `gensim`. It will be your install directory, if you can find it, but you can also view a (static, non-runnable) version inside the `gensim` source code repository at:

https://github.com/RaRe-Technologies/gensim/blob/develop/docs/notebooks/doc2vec-lee.ipynb